# VBScript to refresh Desktop in Wix or MSI

Tags: vbscript, wix, windows-installer

My installer creates the reg key under HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace which creates an icon on the desktop during installation but after uninstallation, that icon stays until I press F5. 
So I googled and found it from [here](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/ezine/ezine89.htm#Version_2_-_SendKeys_Refreshes_your_Desktop_), so I added :

```
<CustomAction Id="CA_RefreshDesktopVB" Script="vbscript">
<![CDATA[
    Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
    strDesktop = WSHShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop") 
    WSHShell.AppActivate strDesktop
    WSHShell.SendKeys "{F5}"
]]>
</CustomAction>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
...
<Custom Action="CA_RefreshDesktopVB" OnExit="success"/>
```

However, it didn't refresh when the uninstallation finished. Did I do something wrong or is this simply beyond VB Script?

Comment: If you log the uninstall does it show that the custom action is being run?

Comment: Yes, it did. Note that since the icon wasn't created under user profile's "Desktop", e.g. C:\Users\john\Desktop or C:\Users\public\Desktop, it didn't work I think.

Comment: Well, I gave up using VBScript. Instead, I just created CA Type 1 using shell API's, e.g. SHGetSpecialFolderLocation() and SHChangeNotify() b/c I know this works.

Answer (score 2):

[`AppActivate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzcddbek.aspx) takes either the window title or the application's process ID (but not folder path!) as a parameter. In case of Windows desktop, the window title as reported by Spy++ is "Program Manager" (at least on my English Vista). Change your script to the following and see if it works:

```
Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WSHShell.AppActivate "Program Manager"
WSHShell.SendKeys "{F5}"
```